# Importing a text file into R

Tags: r

I have a text file which contains over 100,000 rows which I download weekly from SAP. it is downloaded as pages and each page contains the same header along with dashed line. a minimal example with two pages each containing only two items is below.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
|date              |Material          |Description         |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
|10/04/2013        |WM.5597394        |PNEUMATIC           |
|11/07/2013        |GB.D040790        |RING                |
------------------------------------------------------------

------------------------------------------------------------
|date              |Material          |Description         |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
|08/06/2013        |WM.4M01004A05     |TOUCHEUR            |
|08/06/2013        |WM.4M010108-1     |LEVER               |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

what I would like to do is import this file into R with only one header and no dash lines. I tried:

```
read.table( "myfile.txt",  sep = "|", fill=TRUE)
```

Many thanks

Comment: Is the example the content of a single or of two files?

Comment: all rows are contained in a single text file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another `readLines` approach:

```
l <- readLines("myfile.txt")

# remove unnecessary lines
l <- grep("^\\|?-+\\|?$|^$", l, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)

# remove duplicated headers
l2 <- c(l[1], l[-1][l[-1] != l[1]])

# split
lsplit <- strsplit(l2, "\\s*\\|")

# create data frame
dat <- setNames(data.frame(do.call(rbind, lsplit[-1])[ , -1]), lsplit[[1]][-1])


        date      Material Description
1 10/04/2013    WM.5597394   PNEUMATIC
2 11/07/2013    GB.D040790        RING
3 08/06/2013 WM.4M01004A05    TOUCHEUR
4 08/06/2013 WM.4M010108-1       LEVER
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pre-process file like text, then use `read.table`:

```
lines <- readLines("myfile.txt")
lines <- sapply(lines, gsub, pattern="[-]{2,}|[|]", replacement="")
lines <- c(lines[2], lines[lines!="" & lines!=lines[2]])

read.table(text=lines, header=T)
```

gives

```
        date      Material Description
1 10/04/2013    WM.5597394   PNEUMATIC
2 11/07/2013    GB.D040790        RING
3 08/06/2013 WM.4M01004A05    TOUCHEUR
4 08/06/2013 WM.4M010108-1       LEVER
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `readLines` and `read.table` (may be not very efficient):

```
ll <- readLines(textConnection(txt))
dat <- read.table(text=ll[!grepl('--',ll)],sep='|',header=TRUE)[,-c(1,5)]
dat[!grepl('date',dat$date),]
            date           Material          Description
1 10/04/2013         WM.5597394         PNEUMATIC           
2 11/07/2013         GB.D040790         RING                
4 08/06/2013         WM.4M01004A05      TOUCHEUR            
5 08/06/2013         WM.4M010108-1      LEVER
```

Comment: It filters 'WM.4M010108-1'

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by the others answers, `readLines` is the way to go

```
sap <- readLines("myfile.txt")
sap <- gsub("(^\\||\\|$|\\-{2,}|\\s+)", "", sap)
sap <- sap[nchar(sap) > 0]
ind <- grep("^date", sap)
header <- sap[ind]
header <- unique(unlist(strsplit(header, "\\|")))
sap <- sap[-ind]

sap <- read.table(text = sap, sep = "|",
                  col.names = header,
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(sap)
##         date      Material Description
## 1 10/04/2013    WM.5597394   PNEUMATIC
## 2 11/07/2013    GB.D040790        RING
## 3 08/06/2013 WM.4M01004A05    TOUCHEUR
## 4 08/06/2013  WM.4M0101081-1       LEVER
```

Comment: It removes "-" in Material column, last row

Answer (score -1):

You may have to write a custom read.file() function.
I suggest to start with scan(), read each line as an element of a vector and then manipulate each line according to its content