# Proportional substraction from multiple variables

Tags: r, accumulate

I have two variables that change over time. Addition is known, but as for substraction, I know only the sum that needs to be substracted, while I want to substract it from both variables proportionally.

Here is an example of a dataset

```r
df = data.frame(id = c(rep(1,5), rep(2,3)),
                ord = c(1:5, 1:3),
                a = c(10, NA, 20, 0, NA, 0, 15, NA),
                b = c(0, NA, 0, 15, NA, 10, 0, NA),
                substract = c(NA, -5, NA, NA, -10, NA, NA, -15)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(all = sum(c(a, b, substract), na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  arrange(id, ord) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(all = cumsum(all)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

So, I want to replace `NA` in `a` and `b` with the value from `substract`, multiplied by cumulative sum of `a` and `b` respectively, divided by value in `all` right before the `NA`. The problem is, that after each replacement, the next replacement should take into account all the previous replacements, as cumulative sum of `a` and `b` will change after that.

I have a solution with a `while` loop that works, but is highly ineffective. The original dataset is huge, so it is not an option for me, but it might give some additional insight on what I would like to achieve.

```r
test = df %>% 
  group_by(id)
while(any(is.na(test$a))){
  test = test %>% 
    mutate(across(c("a", "b"), ~ ifelse(is.na(.x), lag(cumsum(.x)) / lag(all) * substract, .x)))
}
```

Could anyone suggest a more effective solution? Like, if there was any way to make `mutate` function save changes after each mutation (so it does not need to be put into a while loop) or something?

EDIT: [user63230](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4083743/user63230) suggested using [recursive functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868104/recursive-function-using-dplyr). It does seem to be what I wanted, but I still have difficulties in their application to my case. `accumulate2()` accepts only 3-arguments function and does not seem to work with `lag()` (as I need not only the previous value of the current variable), so it seems to be not enough. Maybe there is a way to make it work, but I have not discovered it yet. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: I think you want a recursive function similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868104/recursive-function-using-dplyr

Comment: Thanks, it seems similar to what I imagined, at least on paper. I still have troubles in understanding how to apply it to my case, but at least I have some direction now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a similar approach as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53434881/4083743), I think this would work, although not pretty:

```
library(dplyr)
sp <- split(df, df$id)
list_of_dfs <- lapply(sp, function(x){
  for(i in which(is.na(x$a))){
    tmp <- x[seq_len(i), ]
    x$a[i] <- tail(cumsum(tmp$a)[!is.na(cumsum(tmp$a))], 1)/tail(dplyr::lag(tmp$all), 1)*tail((tmp$substract), 1)
  }
  x
})
bind_rows(list_of_dfs)
#      id   ord     a     b substract   all
#   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1 10        0        NA    10
# 2     1     2 -5       NA        -5     5
# 3     1     3 20        0        NA    25
# 4     1     4  0       15        NA    40
# 5     1     5 -6.25    NA       -10    30
# 6     2     1  0       10        NA    10
# 7     2     2 15        0        NA    25
# 8     2     3 -9       NA       -15    10
```

Can be repeated/automated for `b` if suitable?