# Setting up a conditional group_by

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

I have a set of data that looks as such:

```
+----------+------------+-------+-------+
|  step1   |   step2    | step3 | step4 |
+----------+------------+-------+-------+
| Region 1 | District A | 1A    |   571 |
| Region 1 | District A | 1A    |   356 |
| Region 1 | District A | 1B    |   765 |
| Region 1 | District B | 1B    |   752 |
| Region 2 | District C | 2C    |   885 |
| Region 2 | District C | 2D    |    73 |
| Region 2 | District D | 2D    |   241 |
| Region 2 | District D | 2D    |   823 |
| Region 3 | District E | 3E    |   196 |
| Region 3 | District E | 3E    |   103 |
| Region 3 | District F | 3E    |   443 |
| Region 3 | District F | 3F    |   197 |
+----------+------------+-------+-------+
```

I have setup the following script, which in the manner it is written, uses the `selectizeGroupServer` to automatically setup filtering between step1, step2, and step3 so they're linked together (i.e. If you filter for Region 1 it will only return the relevant options in Step2 and Step3.

The script below returns the results I'm looking for if you wanted it to `group_by_all` in a straight forward manner. So on initial run, it will show the graphed output of all 11 results. If I filter by Region 1, it will return a graph of all four figures in step4 linked to Region 1.

But I want to set it up in a way where when I select an option, it will actually group by the hierarchy option below it. So if I filter by Region 1, it will instead return two columns: The summed aggregate of District A (1692) and the summed aggregate of District B (752). If I have both Region 1 AND District A selected, it would return two columns: The aggregate of 1A (927) and the aggregate of 1B that is tied to District A (765).

How may I set it up in a way that accomplishes this?

```
library(highcharter)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)

step1 <- c('Region 1', 'Region 1', 'Region 1', 'Region 1', 'Region 2', 'Region 2', 'Region 2', 'Region 2', 'Region 3', 'Region 3', 'Region 3', 'Region 3')
step2 <- c('District A', 'District A', 'District A', 'District B', 'District C', 'District C', 'District D', 'District D', 'District E', 'District E', 'District F', 'District F')
step3 <- c('1A', '1A', '1B', '1B', '2C', '2D', '2D', '2D', '3E', '3E', '3E', '3F')
step4 <- c(571,356,765,752,885,73,241,823,196,103,443,197)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 5, offset = 1,
      panel(
        selectizeGroupUI(
          id = "foo",
          params = list(
            Step1 = list(inputId = "step1", title = "Step1:"),
            Step2 = list(inputId = "step2", title = "Step2:"),
            Step3 = list(inputId = "step3", title = "Step3:")
          ))
      ),
      highchartOutput(outputId = "table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  abc <- callModule(
    module = selectizeGroupServer,
    id = "foo",
    data = df,
    vars = c("step1", "step2", "step3")
  )

  output$table <- renderHighchart({

    bar <- abc()

    xyz <- bar %>% filter(is.null(input$step1) | step1 %in% input$step1,
                        is.null(input$step2) | step2 %in% input$step2,
                        is.null(input$step3) | step3 %in% input$step3) %>% group_by_all() %>% summarise(results = sum(step4))


    highchart() %>% hc_add_series(data = xyz, type = "column", hcaes(y = results),
                                  showInLegend = TRUE) %>% hc_add_theme(hc_theme_flat())


  })


}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Disclosure: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52023709/what-can-r-do-about-a-messy-data-format) was asked by me.

Comment: @akrun - what do you mean by dput? You can see what df looks like in the table above.

Comment: @akrun just edited the script to make it easy to throw into a dataframe or however you think is best at setting it up

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. Thanks for catching that. Edited my initial post.

Comment: @akrun Why did you delete your comments?

Comment: Because you already formatted it and is no longer needed

Comment: Ah got it haha. Thanks. Look forward to your answer!

Comment: One thing I am trying to understand is how the `input`s are getting changed here.  In your case, you are doing the `filter` with `|`.  If you need a hierarchial group, it is much simpler with `library(data.table);dt1 <- as.data.table(df1); rollup(dt1, j = sum(step4), by =  c("step1", "step2", "step3"))` and then do the `filter`

Comment: Also, an option is to `filter` with `filter_at`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204275/discussion-between-gooponyagrinch-and-akrun).

Comment: @akrun Whatever you think is the best way to answer it, you're welcome to make whatever changes you want!

Comment: @akrun you seem to know this much better than I do, so I'm more than open to hearing how you would write it. Don't worry about fully abiding my initial script.

Comment: sorry, I tried it, I have some other things came up.  I have to go.  I hope you get a response from somebody or else will try later.  Thank you

Comment: @akrun Thanks. I'll keep trying, but I'll probably need your help (assuming someone else doesn't answer).

Comment: Welp looks like I'm not getting this one answered :(

Answer (score 2):

First, we need to find out which column to group by. In this case, I assume it is the first column with more than 1 option. The rest of the code is pretty similar, except for the `group_by_all` being replaced by `group_by_at`.

```
output$table <- renderHighchart({

        bar <- abc()

        # find out which column to group by (first column with more than 1 distinct value)
        summ_column <- bar %>%
            summarise_all(~ length(unique(.))) %>% {colnames(.)[.>1]} %>% first()

        xyz <- bar %>% group_by_at(summ_column) %>% summarise(results = sum(step4))


        highchart() %>% hc_add_series(data = xyz, type = "column", hcaes(y = results),
                                      showInLegend = TRUE) %>% hc_add_theme(hc_theme_flat())


    })
```

This will not work if you select more than 1 value for a single option, but that solution should be pretty similar.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are looking for `aggregate`. Please check the following:

```
library(highcharter)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
# library(dplyr)

DF <- data.frame(
  step1 = c('Region 1', 'Region 1', 'Region 1', 'Region 1', 'Region 2', 'Region 2', 'Region 2', 'Region 2', 'Region 3', 'Region 3', 'Region 3', 'Region 3'),
  step2 = c('District A', 'District A', 'District A', 'District B', 'District C', 'District C', 'District D', 'District D', 'District E', 'District E', 'District F', 'District F'),
  step3 = c('1A', '1A', '1B', '1B', '2C', '2D', '2D', '2D', '3E', '3E', '3E', '3F'),
  step4 = c(571,356,765,752,885,73,241,823,196,103,443,197),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 5, offset = 1,
      panel(
        selectizeGroupUI(
          id = "foo",
          params = list(
            Step1 = list(inputId = "step1", title = "Step1:"),
            Step2 = list(inputId = "step2", title = "Step2:"),
            Step3 = list(inputId = "step3", title = "Step3:")
          ))
      ),
      highchartOutput(outputId = "table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  abc <- callModule(
    module = selectizeGroupServer,
    id = "foo",
    data = DF,
    vars = c("step1", "step2", "step3")
  )

  output$table <- renderHighchart({
    req(abc())
    bar <- aggregate(step4 ~ step1+step2, abc(), sum)
    highchart() %>% hc_add_series(data = bar, type = "column", hcaes(y = step4), showInLegend = TRUE) %>% hc_add_theme(hc_theme_flat())
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Result]