# Got another columns value by another column max in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I got a dataframe that looks like this.

```
+---+------+------+------+------+
|   | Name | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+---+------+------+------+------+
| 1 |   A  |  10  |  0   |  0   |
| 2 |   B  |  5   |  20  |  5   |
| 3 |   C  |  15  |  15  |  20  |
| 4 |   D  |  20  |  5   |  15  |
| 5 |   F  |  0   |  10  |  15  |
+---+------+------+------+------+
```

I want the name of maximum for each column. The expected output should look like this:

```
+---+------+------+
|   |  col |  MAX |
+---+------+------+
| 1 | col1 |   D  |
| 2 | col2 |   B  |
| 3 | col3 |   C  |
+---+------+------+
```

how do I code it??

Comment: Please, use `dput` to provide us with your data. The chances of getting a solution increases a lot by doing that!

Comment: This may help you to use `dput`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994249/example-of-using-dput

Comment: See my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52023709/what-can-r-do-about-a-messy-data-format) about your posted data format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df2 = melt(df, id.vars="Name", variable.name="col")
df2 = df2[, .SD[which.max(value)], by = col][, c("col", "Name")]
names(df2)[2] = "MAX"
```

**Output:**

```
df2

    col MAX
1: col1   D
2: col2   B
3: col3   C
```

---

### dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

df2 = df %>% 
  gather(key="col", value="Value", 2:4) %>% 
  top_n(1, Value) %>%
  rename_at(1, ~"MAX") %>% 
  select(c("col", "MAX"))
```

**Output:**

```
df2

  col MAX
1 col1   D
2 col2   B
3 col3   C
```

---

### base R

It could perhaps also work a bit more simply or asthethic (Update: see akruns `base R` solution, which is way better)...

```
df2 = reshape(df, direction="long", varying=2:4, v.names="value")
df2 = df2[order(-df2$value), ]
df2 = df2[!duplicated(df2$time), c("time", "Name")]
names(df2) = c("col", "MAX")
df2$col = paste0("col", df2$col)
rownames(df2) = NULL
```

**Output:**

```
df2

   col MAX
1 col1   D
2 col2   B
3 col3   C
```

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can do

```
stack(sapply(df1[-1], \(x) df1$Name[which.max(x)]))[2:1]
   ind values
1 col1      D
2 col2      B
3 col3      C
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "F"), col1 = c(10L, 
5L, 15L, 20L, 0L), col2 = c(0L, 20L, 15L, 5L, 10L), col3 = c(0L, 
5L, 20L, 15L, 15L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Comment: Great `base R` solution! Way better than mine, thanks for sharing, I referenced to it.