# How can I read txt file into a dataframe and separate some of its content elsewhere?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-analysis

The .txt file I have is like:

[image]

I want to load the table as a dataframe and want to save the variable info for reference. How can I do this?

Here is the link to the data:
https://www.sao.ru/lv/lvgdb/article/suites_dw_Table1.txt

Comment: The .txt file in text form would be great (to reproduce)!

Comment: In my opinion you can achieve it with `readLines`, but I agree, .tx file would be great to provide full answer.

Comment: Like @DominikŻabiński start with `readLines`, then note that the prologue is separated from the data table by a blank line and use this knowledge to keep the table only, then maybe something along the lines of [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52023709/what-can-r-do-about-a-messy-data-format).

Comment: https://www.sao.ru/lv/lvgdb/article/suites_dw_Table1.txt

Comment: Not resolved. Have given the link to the file. Looking for detailed solution

Answer (score 2):

You can read the file with `readLines`, find the line with the "--------" in it, then extract the line before and all lines after this. Feed the result to `read.table`

```r
txt <- readLines("https://www.sao.ru/lv/lvgdb/article/suites_dw_Table1.txt")

underline <- grep("--------", txt)

df <- read.table(text = txt[c(underline - 1, (underline + 1):length(txt))], 
                 sep = "|", header = TRUE)

dplyr::tibble(df)
#> # A tibble: 796 x 12
#>    name        a_26   m_b log_lk log_m26 log_mhi   vlg   ti1 md        D delta~1
#>    <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 " HolmIX ~  2.96 -13.6   7.7     8.53 "  8.4~   192   5.1 " ME~  3.61      88
#>  2 " ClumpI ~  0.2   -8.3   5.57   NA    "     ~   -25   4.2 " ME~  3.6     -129
#>  3 " KDG061 ~  1.55 -12.9   8.09   NA    "     ~   360   4   " ME~  3.6      256
#>  4 " [CKT200~  0.88 -10.1   6.29   NA    "     ~   -46   4   " ME~  3.6     -150
#>  5 " ClumpII~  0.11  -8.3   5.57   NA    "     ~    19   3.9 " ME~  3.6      -85
#>  6 " NGC2976~  6.17 -17.1   9.42    9.15 "  8.0~   142   2.9 " ME~  3.56      38
#>  7 " MESSIER~ 13.2  -19.6  10.6     9.86 "  8.9~   328   2.8 " ME~  3.53     224
#>  8 " KDG064 ~  2.19 -12.6   7.98   NA    "     ~   121   2.7 " ME~  3.7       17
#>  9 " [CKT200~  0.87  -9.6   6.8    NA    "     ~    NA   2.5 " ME~  3.66      NA
#> 10 " IKN    ~  3.15 -11.6   7.6    NA    " <6.2~    -1   2.5 " ME~  3.75    -105
#> # ... with 786 more rows, 1 more variable: count <int>, and abbreviated
#> #   variable name 1: delta_vlg
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Upvote but you could `trimws` the character columns

Comment: Can you show how to save the column description in another variable? Also, if possible, please describe what you did above in the "read.table()" in a bit more detail. I am new so having hard time to understand.

Comment: The `read.table` is literally reading the table data. To get it to do this, we have to pass it only the lines of the file that have the table, minus the line with the "----" in it, which has the index `underline`. So `underline - 1` is the header row, and `(underline + 1):length(txt)` is from the first line of data to the end of the file. So `txt[c(underline - 1, (underline + 1):length(txt))]` is just the table we want to read. The `sep = "|"` just tells `read.table` that the cells are demarcated by the pipe symbol "|".

Comment: As for storing the textual data, it's not clear how you would want to store this other than in the format it is already in.  But yes, it's possible I guess. What format do you want it in?